# Pausing users background music

Tags: ios, swift3, background-music

In the app we are developing, if music is playing when the app starts, we would like to allow it to continue. Within the app itself, this is fine and working, however, if an Interstitial Ad is shown, common sense and best practice dictate that we should pause this background music in case the Interstitial has music of its own. We would then ideally restart the music when the Interstitial is dismissed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a class **[MPMusic​Player​Controller](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller)** which handles Music app functions.It has some class methods like system​Music​Player() that may help in achieving it. But the problem is with any third party app. Suppose music is being played via any third party app. So in this case you won't be able to get access to its method and in case of any interrupt ,like you said, that will be paused.

Comment: Not true; it's quite easy to pause music even if it's another app.

Comment: If you pause it you can resume it — simple as that. Why would it be a one way operation; that makes absolutely no sense...

Comment: Can you control volume through this mechanism to support fade in/out?